# interval in intervals table

Tags: sql, sql-server, algorithm, date, intervals

I have table with two columns like this:

```
+-----------+------------+
|   FROM    |     TO     |
+-----------+------------+
|2015-03-01 | 2015-03-04 |
|2015-03-05 | 2015-03-09 |
+-----------+------------+
```

And I want to write the function which will take two arguments - DateFrom, and DateTo, and check this interval. For example, if function takes `DateFrom = 2015-03-03`, and `DateTo = 2015-03-08` as arguments it should return `true`, because every day from this interval is in table.

But if table is like this:

```
+-----------+------------+
|   FROM    |     TO     |
+-----------+------------+
|2015-03-01 | 2015-03-04 |
|2015-03-06 | 2015-03-09 |
+-----------+------------+
```

the function should return `false`, because `2015-03-05` isn't in table. Any idea for algorithm? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Just as a side note, if this query will be used often (`X` times more than inserts & deletions), I would consider an additional table that keeps the ranges of dates you have. This will add a cost on insertions & deletions of the main table, but will speed up the query.

Comment: Are the ranges in the table guaranteed to be non-overlapping, or could your first table have a row with `From = 2013-05-07` and `To = 2013-06-01`?  What is the table's name? It is much harder to get good answers when the table is anonymous (but it is a surprisingly common mistake to omit the table name).  You can always invent one — but it's work you should do, not those trying to answer your question.

Comment: Unfortunately I can not do this, because system is large and many procedures using this table, so if I will change it, then I will have to change all objects depend on.

Comment: @user3271955 `if exists (select Froms,Tos from @temp where Froms <= @DateFrom AND Tos >= @DateTo)
select 1;
else
select 0;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't already have calendar table, you can use tally table for this:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE
    (
      FromDate DATE ,
      ToDate DATE
    )

INSERT  INTO @t
VALUES  ( '2015-03-01', '2015-03-04' ),
        ( '2015-03-05', '2015-03-09' )

DECLARE @from DATE =  '2015-03-03', @to DATE = '2015-03-08'

;WITH cte1 AS(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS d
             FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) a(n)
             CROSS JOIN (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) b(n)
             CROSS JOIN (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) c(n)),
      cte2 AS(SELECT DATEADD(dd, d - 1, @from) AS d 
              FROM cte1 
              WHERE DATEADD(dd, d - 1, @from) <= @to)

SELECT  CASE WHEN EXISTS ( SELECT *
                           FROM cte2
                           WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT *
                                              FROM   @t t
                                              WHERE  d BETWEEN t.FromDate AND t.ToDate ) )
             THEN 0
             ELSE 1
        END AS IntervalExists
```

It will work for interval with 1000 days difference. If more needed just add more `cross joins`(one `cross join` will multiply interval by 10).

Comment: Great! Thank you very much. It works well, exactly I was expected. Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to perform this operation on a table to pass through each row in the table. I would advise you to go with a usp (User Stored Procedure)

Below is the sample code to do the same:

```
CREATE PROC usp_CheckInterval
(
@DateFrom Date ,
@DateTo Date ,
@ReturnStatus bit OUTPUT
)
AS
BEGIN TRY

SET NOCOUNT ON;

IF(EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM [YourTable] WHERE [StartDate] < @DateFrom AND [EndDate] > @DateTo))
BEGIN
SET @ReturnStatus = 0
END

ELSE
BEGIN
SET @ReturnStatus = 1
END

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    --Catch Here
END CATCH;
```

Sample Execution:

```
DECLARE @RC int
DECLARE @DateFrom date = GETDATE()
DECLARE @DateTo date =  GETDATE()
DECLARE @ReturnStatus bit

-- TODO: Set parameter values here.

EXECUTE @RC = [dbo].[usp_CheckInterval] 
   @DateFrom
  ,@DateTo
  ,@ReturnStatus OUTPUT   

SELECT @ReturnStatus
```

Let me know how it pans out.

Comment: Thanks for your trying to help, but problem is more complicated. Your procedure will work well if I want to check one row, but DateFrom can be in first row, and DateTo can be in second row if difference between DateTo from first row and DateFrom from second row is max one day. It may also be that interval will be separated into several rows, more than two.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is a function to create running numbers:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetRunningNumbers](@counter INT=10000000, @StartAt INT=0)
RETURNS TABLE
AS 
RETURN
WITH E1(N) AS( -- 10 ^ 1 = 10 rows
    SELECT 1 FROM(VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))t(N)
),
E2(N) AS(SELECT 1 FROM E1 a CROSS JOIN E1 b), -- 10 ^ 2 = 100 rows
E4(N) AS(SELECT 1 FROM E2 a CROSS JOIN E2 b), -- 10 ^ 4 = 10,000 rows
E8(N) AS(SELECT 1 FROM E4 a CROSS JOIN E4 b), -- 10 ^ 8 = 10,000,000 rows
CteTally AS(
    SELECT TOP(ISNULL(@counter,1000000)) ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY(SELECT NULL)) -1 + ISNULL(@StartAt,0) As Nmbr
    FROM E8
)
SELECT * FROM CteTally;
GO
```

With this function you can do this as one-liner:

```
    DECLARE @tbl TABLE(d1 DATETIME, d2 DATETIME);
    INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES({d'2015-03-01'},{d'2015-03-04'})
                          ,({d'2015-03-05'},{d'2015-03-09'}); 

    DECLARE @CheckStart DATETIME={d'2015-03-03'};
    DECLARE @CheckEnd DATETIME={d'2015-03-08'};

    --Check if all dates between these two checkdates are coverd within your table (be aware of the possible time component of a DATETIME!):
WITH AllCheckDates AS
(
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY,Nmbr,@CheckStart) AS RunningDate
    FROM dbo.GetRunningNumbers(DATEDIFF(DAY,@CheckStart,@CheckEnd)+1,0)
)
SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM AllCheckDates WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM @tbl AS t WHERE RunningDate BETWEEN t.d1 AND t.d2 ) )
            THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS AllDatesCoveredInIntervall
```

Now once again with the gap at 2015-04-05:

```
    DELETE FROM @tbl;
    INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES({d'2015-03-01'},{d'2015-03-04'})
                          ,({d'2015-03-06'},{d'2015-03-09'}); 

    --Same query, should deliver false now...
WITH AllCheckDates AS
(
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY,Nmbr,@CheckStart) AS RunningDate
    FROM dbo.GetRunningNumbers(DATEDIFF(DAY,@CheckStart,@CheckEnd)+1,0)
)
SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM AllCheckDates WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM @tbl AS t WHERE RunningDate BETWEEN t.d1 AND t.d2 ) )
            THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS AllDatesCoveredInIntervall 
GO
```

Just for cleanup...

```
DROP FUNCTION dbo.GetRunningNumbers;
GO
```