# Create a view using SQL Server with repeating rows and new column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, view

I have a table with the following columns.

```
EVAL_ID    | GGRP_ID     | GOAL_ID 
1            1             1    
2            2             1
2            2             2
3            1             3
```

I want to create a view with another columns called GOAL_VERSION which has values from 1 to 3. So that each row from the above table should be duplicated 5 times for different GOAL_VERSION numbers. The out put should be like this.

```
EVAL_ID    | GGRP_ID     | GOAL_ID    |GOAL_VERSION 
1            1             1            1
1            1             1            2
1            1             1            3
1            1             1            4
1            1             1            5
2            2             1            1
2            2             1            2
2            2             1            3
2            2             1            4
2            2             1            5
```

How can I do that. Help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is it this you are looking for?

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(EVAL_ID INT,GGRP_ID INT,GOAL_ID INT);
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 (1,1,1)   
,(2,2,1)
,(2,2,2)
,(3,1,3);

SELECT tbl.*
      ,x.Nr
FROM @tbl AS tbl
CROSS JOIN (VALUES(1),(2),(3),(4),(5)) AS x(Nr)
```

#### EDIT: Varying count of repetition

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(EVAL_ID INT,GGRP_ID INT,GOAL_ID INT);
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 (1,1,1)   
,(2,2,1)
,(2,2,2)
,(3,1,3);

DECLARE @tblCountOfRep TABLE(CountOfRep INT);
INSERT INTO @tblCountOfRep VALUES(3);

SELECT tbl.*
      ,y.Nr
FROM @tbl AS tbl
CROSS JOIN (SELECT TOP (SELECT CountOfRep FROM @tblCountOfRep) * FROM(VALUES(1),(2),(3),(4),(5) /*add the max count here*/) AS x(Nr)) AS y
```

In this case I'd prefer I numbers table...

Comment: You can shorten this `CROSS JOIN (VALUES(1),(2),(3),(4),(5)) AS x(Nr)`

Comment: What if the number of the columns are not fix. which means each time the view is called the number should me get from another table as the MAX value.

Comment: @jayz, sorry, don't understand... If your "normal" `SELECT * FROM Somewhere` returns X columns in 20 Rows the `CROSS JOIN` would add one more column and return 100 rows all numbered from 1 to 5 ...`

Comment: Sorry. I mean If The number of times each row duplicates should be varied like it has to be collected form the data of another table(1-5 may be changed to 1-6 or 1-7) what should I do. So that VALUES(1),(2),(3),(4),(5) this should me a variable or something like that?

Comment: Thank you. That solved my problem. But I always have to mention a upper limit. right?

Comment: @jayz Well, you might use inside the `TOP` a `SELECT ISNULL(CountOfRep,1000000) FROM ...`

Comment: I mean I have to include this part "VALUES(1),(2),(3),(4),(5) /*add the max count here*/" with the max number like VALUES(1),(2),(3),(4),(5) .......(100000) or is there any other way to make this unlimited?

Comment: @jayz, you might use a table valued function to create millions of numbers in milliseconds. I posted one example here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32755424/5089204

Comment: I'll try. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at CROSS JOIN. If you make a table that's got one column with the 5 rows you want you can just CROSS JOIN it to get the result you're after.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using a `CTE` and `CROSS APPLY`:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT 1 AS GOAL_VERSION
    UNION
    SELECT 2
    UNION
    SELECT 3
    UNION
    SELECT 4
    UNION
    SELECT 5
)
SELECT * FROM <your table>
CROSS APPLY CTE
```

Answer (score 0):

use "with" (cte) with rank clause for creating view.

Answer (score -1):

If you have a numbers table in SQL database, you can cross join your table with the numbers table for numbers between 1 and 5

Here is my SQL solution for your requirement

```
select 
   goals.*, 
   n.i as GOAL_VERSION
from goals, dbo.NumbersTable(1,5,1) n
```

And here is the modified version with "cross join" as suggested in the comments

```
select 
   goals.*, 
   n.i as GOAL_VERSION
from goals
cross join dbo.NumbersTable(1,5,1) n
```

You can realize, I used a SQL table-valued function for [SQL numbers table](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/sql-server-tsql-cte-numbers-table.aspx)
Please create that SQL function using the source codes given in the referred tutorial
I hope it helps,

Comment: instead of the simple "old fashioned" join with the comma it is better to use `CROSS JOIN`... Btw: I'm not the down-voter...

Comment: no problem :) what I mentioned actually in my post is the use of numbers table. Some use it from master database sys..spt_values or any other resource. But I found it very handy to keep a table of function for dates and numbers table..

Comment: Yes, a number's table is very handy. I use one with several side columns (Day-index, week-index, ...) to get lighting fast approaches to datetime calculations